# How to add fields_for onchange of select tag like link_to_add_fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, fields-for

Is there any custom method like `onchange_to_add_fields` like `link_to_add_fields` as defined in [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

I want to make a custom `onchange_to_add_fields` like `link_to_add_fields`. But not able to understand how to accomplish this. I just need some instructions like how it will work or is there any workaround to this problem or any other way to implement association using `accept_nested_attributes_for` association.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use gem 'nested_form' if you want to implement add_field in ajax way

https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: Thanks. But does this gem support adding fields on change of select tag?

Comment: No. But I think you can write the same event on onchange which is written on click of 'add more'

Comment: You need to override the jquery_nested_form.js file in nested_form gem.